# how to declare two packages with their activities in android manifest file?

Tags: android, android-manifest

I have **two packages** in my android application. How to mention those different packages along with their activities in android manifest file?In my code I have given as

```
<manifest package="com.tabwidget">
    <application>
        <activity android:name=".com.tabwidget.Tab"></activity>
        <activity android:name=".com.tabwidget.TabHostProvider"></activity>
        <activity android:name=".com.tabwidget.TabView"></activity>
    </application>
</manifest>                  
<manifest package="com.kpbird.tabbarcontrol">
    <application>
        <activity android:name=".com.kpbird.tabbarcontrol.TabbarView"></activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

But I am getting exception Unable to find explicit activity class ...........Where was i wrong? Please help me...........

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It seems you have made a few mistakes in the XML:

```
<manifest package="com.tabwidget">
    <application>

        1) BELOW: starting the names by "." means that
        you are implicitely extending the package prefix defined in the package 
        attribute of the manifest XML tag. 
        For example, if your package is "com.tabwidget", defining".MyActivity"
        will be interpreted as "com.tabwidget.MyActivity"
        By removing the first ".", you use an explicit notation instead:
        whatever your package is, "com.tabwidget.MyActivity" is interpreted
        as "com.tabwidget.MyActivity"
        <activity android:name=".com.tabwidget.Tab"></activity>
        <activity android:name=".com.tabwidget.TabHostProvider"></activity>
        <activity android:name=".com.tabwidget.TabView"></activity>
    </application>
</manifest>                  

2) BELOW: a manifest file should only contain one manifest XML tag:
<manifest package="com.kpbird.tabbarcontrol">
    <application>

        3) BELOW: same mistake as 1)
        <activity android:name=".com.kpbird.tabbarcontrol.TabbarView"></activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

What follows should work. It fixes these 3 mistakes:

```
<manifest package="com.kpbird.tabbarcontrol">
    <application>
        <activity android:name="com.tabwidget.Tab"></activity>
        <activity android:name="com.tabwidget.TabHostProvider"></activity>
        <activity android:name="com.tabwidget.TabView"></activity>
        <activity android:name=".TabbarView"></activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: thanks for your response.But here TabbarView Activity belongs to different package. How to place that package in manifest file? You said that there can be only one manifest tag in manifest.xml file.

Comment: I used `<manifest package="com.kpbird.tabbarcontrol">` in that purpose. In my manifest file, your app will be called "com.kpbird.tabbarcontrol", it will use `com.tabwidget.*` by the use of explicit notations in the `activity` tags and will use `com.kpbird.tabbarcontrol.TabbarView` by the use of an implicit notation. You may want to invert this. In that case use "com.tabwidget" as the package name, use implicit notation for the various Tabwidget activities, and use explicit notation for TabbarView

Answer (score 1):

you can do like this . you need no to do any explicit inclusion of different package

```
<manifest package="com.tabwidget">
<application>
    <activity android:name="com.tabwidget.Tab"></activity>
    <activity android:name="com.tabwidget.TabHostProvider"></activity>
    <activity android:name="com.tabwidget.TabView"></activity>
    <activity android:name="com.tabwidget.TabbarView"></activity>
</application>
```