# Declare activity in manifest using the eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, android-manifest

I just want to know how can i declare the activity or add my activity in the manifest by using the eclipse GUI?..I do this in AndroidMaifest.xml-> application->click add button->create new top level element then select the Acitivity in the list->browse?but i could not see my activity.maybe i am wrong,can you help me on this please.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Add like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7160285/how-to-declare-two-packages-with-their-activities-in-android-manifest-file?rq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### In `<application />` tag

```
<activity
    android:name="YourActivity" >
</activity>
```

### OR from Application Tab:

[image: Add Activity]

### **NOTE: YOU MUST  `extends Activity` in your Activity class.**

Answer (score 3):

Seems to be you set the name value on the application tab. That should work fine and dandy

[image]

It should come out looking like this:

[image]

If you notice when you add an application node, aka activities, broadcast receivers, and services, you set the name of these as the "path" to the class. That's the same with the Application's name.

Comment: Hi Thank you for the quick reply,I also have mistakes I forgot to extend the acitivity in my java class that i created.

Comment: That could do it, I didn't read your question right sorry. Maybe you should accept Darshak's answer instead :).

Comment: I didn't read the question right :P. No reason for me to get the accepted answer :)

Answer (score 1):

Easy. follow the steps.

1. Open your manifest file in Eclipse.

2. In the bottom tab you will find five options. Manifest, Application, Permissions, Instruments, Your_Manifest.xml

3. Click on Application tab and you will see nice GUI which would look something like this[image]

4. Now see the option Application nodes click on the Add button and it will ask you what you would like to add

5. Select Activity and click ok it will provide you new form kind of thing for you to fill in just add your activity name and other attributes/properties etc.

**PS: This is just too much work for me I follow keyboard way it feels faster. just press Ctrl+Space and it does the work for you. :P**